# "Only allowed to search every 15 seconds" setting for non-logged-in users?

Tags: search

According to EE documentation, you can set the 'seconds between searches' for each member group. But where is the setting for members who are not logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone that's not logged in is part of the "Guest" group:

Members > Member Groups > Edit Member Group (Guest)

Should be here:

/system/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=members&M=edit_member_group&group_id=3

Comment: Thanks! Ellis Lab should add that to their documentation.

Comment: 4midori, what specifically was the missing component to understanding that guest permissions were controlled via the Guest member group? Happy to improve the documentation, but need to know where we failed.